# Proof of the Existence of Bayesian Nash Equilibria

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I found the following two Theorems when studying games with incomplete information.

"Consider a ﬁnite incomplete information (Bayesian) game. Then a mixed strategy Bayesian Nash equilibrium exists."

"Consider a Bayesian game with continuous strategy spaces and continuous types. If strategy sets and type sets are compact, payoﬀ functions are continuous and concave in own strategies, then a pure strategy Bayesian Nash equilibrium exists. "

The lecture slides I found did not have any proofs for the above statements. Does anyone know any good reference/books to look up the said proofs?

Answer (score 0):

It can be found on p. 34 of [Fudenberg and Tirole (1991)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262061414), which is referencing a result obtained separately by Debreu (1952), Glicksberg (1952), and Fan (1952).

The above quotes are likely from the [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-254-game-theory-with-engineering-applications-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_254S10_lec17.pdf) given in an online MIT course by Asu Ozdaglar in 2010. 
Some explanation of the proof and be found in an [earlier lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-254-game-theory-with-engineering-applications-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_254S10_lec05.pdf).